# iPhone won't connect to wifi

Tags: iphone, wifi

My iPhone will not connect to my wireless router, even when I put the password in.

How do I troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: What version of iOS are you using?

Comment: You should also add details about what kind of wireless setup you have (WPA, WPA2, WEP etc) and if it is an n-only connection (as far as I know, iPhones only operate on the 2.4 GHz spectrum, while n-connections operate on 5 GHz by default). And, what happens after you put the password in? Does the wifi icon show up at all? Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 1):

Checking the obvious - you can connect to WiFi on another computer right? The iPhone frequently over-reports the strength of the WiFi connection, so you can see 2 or 3 bars but not actually connect because it times out.

Try holding the iPhone vertically with your fingers at the top and bottom - the WiFi receiver is in the side, so when you hold it with your hands at the sides, it reduces WiFi reception.

Answer (score 1):

I recently solved this problem. Several mobile devices (including the iPhone) just simply won't connect to a network that is broadcasting WPA/WPA2 simultaneously. You have to choose either WPA or WPA2 and then they will connect no problem.